# Finding value of Vo in a circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I have started learning basics about circuits and I stumbled upon this circuit in which I have to find out what is the value of Vo.
I have thought about using mesh method but it is a bit confusing in this circuit and I couldn't figure it out yet.
Could anyone help out, it should not be difficult for anyone with experience.

Thank you.

This is what I have tried using mesh method:
Starting from left side the loops are 1 and then 2(middle top) then 3(middle bottom) then 4.
Mesh 2: -2Vx + (I2-I3) - Vo = 0
Mesh 3: 2 + (I3-I2) + Vx = 0
Mesh 4: 2 + I4 + Vo + I4 = 0

I am not sure if those three were correct, but regardless of that, the one that confused me which I didnt write here is the first loop (Mesh 1) because it would seem for me that it would simply give 3Vx = 0 which is not correct for sure.

Hopefully this shows enough were I might have done something wrong.

[image]

Comment: Do try the methods you have learned sofar and just see how far you get. The "complexity" of a circuit does not mean that the basic mesh methods etc. suddenly stop working. Come back when you have at least tried it and show us what you did. Now you have basically done nothing so this question will be closed.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I have tried as I mentioned but I was facing a problem when trying to do the mesh on the loops on the side which have both a current source and a voltage source together. If somebody could just give me a hint on how to start with that then the rest will be fine I can figure it out. I believe the point of this community is to help people not to instantly reject them because you don't like the question. Not everyone was born an expert you know, giving a little bit of hints can push people forward, so it would be nice if you can do that

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @OlinLathrop This is my own initiative to learn, it is not a homework. I don't understand why everyone acts negatively, you just dis encourage beginners to learn. if you dont want to help then dont, but dont dis encourage people and as I mentioned in the earlier comment it is only a matter of giving a hint on how to start regarding the small problem i faced. I am not asking anyone to come and solve it for me

Comment: Michael, I don't know how much you have used this site but, if you saw how common it is for some student to just post their homework or assignment problems and expect a quick win, it may explain the apparent lack of patience. The truth is that anyone, no matter how inexperienced, will always be given help if they show that they have made some genuine effort. Probably, the way you worded your question made it seem like you didn't try first. Perhaps edit to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @RogerRowland Thank you for the advice, I am new to this site so I did know of the case you mentioned. I have edited the question to show a bit what I started with which should be clear for any expert to know what went wrong. Hopefully now I get some help from someone.

Comment: Excellent. Maybe rephrase that first sentence too? *"I have been given this circuit..."* sounds like homework. *"I am trying to teach myself using a book and this circuit is difficult..."* or something like that would be nearer the truth perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the meshes a,b,c,d for left, top, right, bottom, respectivly:

Becuase of the two current sources:

Ia = 2mA

Ic - Id = 2mA

We also can do KVL for 3 circuits that don't involve current source:

Vo + (Ib-Id)*1k - 2Vx = 0

Vo + (Ib-Id)*1k + Vx -4V - Ic*1k = 0

2Vx + Vx -4 - Ic*1k = 0

Two resistors are given voltage labels and sizes and we know mess current:

Vo = 1k*(Ib - Ic)

Vx = 1k*(Ia - Id)

Now it is simply a matter of solving the simultaneous equations. Which results in:

Ia = 2mA, Ib = 3mA, Ic = 2mA, Id = 0mA, Vo = 1V, Vx = 2V.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see what I did wrong, it is very clear now. This was very helpful, thanks a lot!